# DELETE statement not working

Tags: delete, sybase, sybase-ase

I'm running my database on a Sybase ASE 15.7 server.
A simple delete statement fails without printing any error , I presume there is no permissions problem as I used to delete rows by the past.
Here is what I did from an isql console.

```
1> select count(*) from LOGIN where login="336959686@login.com"
2> go

 -----------
       1

(1 row affected)
1> delete from LOGIN where login="336959686@login.com"
2> go
(0 rows affected)
```

The row wasn't deleted, am I missing something?

LOGIN table definition :

```
1> sp_help LOGIN
2> go
 Name  Owner Object_type Object_status Create_date
 ----- ----- ----------- ------------- -------------------
 LOGIN xxx   user table   -- none --   Dec  7 2010  2:13PM

(1 row affected)
 Column_name            Type     Length Prec Scale Nulls Not_compressed Default_name Rule_name Access_Rule_name Computed_Column_object Identity
 ---------------------- -------- ------ ---- ----- ----- -------------- ------------ --------- ---------------- ---------------------- ----------
 login_oidval           numeric       8   16     0     0              0 NULL         NULL      NULL             NULL                            0
 login                  varchar     165 NULL  NULL     0              0 NULL         NULL      NULL             NULL                            0
 creation_date          datetime      8 NULL  NULL     0              0 NULL         NULL      NULL             NULL                            0
 last_modification_date datetime      8 NULL  NULL     0              0 NULL         NULL      NULL             NULL                            0
 idp_oidval             smallint      2 NULL  NULL     0              0 NULL         NULL      NULL             NULL                            0
Object has the following indexes

 index_name index_keys         index_description    index_max_rows_per_page index_fillfactor index_reservepagegap index_created       index_local
 ---------- ------------------ -------------------- ----------------------- ---------------- -------------------- ------------------- ------------
 PK_LOGIN    login_oidval      nonclustered, unique                       0                0                    0 Dec 10 2010  7:10PM Global Index
 login_idx1  login, idp_oidval nonclustered, unique                       0                0                    0 Jun 10 2011  2:55PM Global Index

(2 rows affected)
 index_ptn_name       index_ptn_seg
 -------------------- -------------
 PK_LOGIN_448001596   default
 login_idx1_448001596 default

(2 rows affected)
No defined keys for this object.
 name  type       partition_type partitions partition_keys
 ----- ---------- -------------- ---------- --------------
 LOGIN base table roundrobin              1 NULL

(1 row affected)

 partition_name  partition_id compression_level pages row_count segment create_date
 --------------- ------------ ----------------- ----- --------- ------- -------------------
 LOGIN_448001596    448001596 none                863     25497 default Feb 12 2014  3:01PM

 Partition_Conditions
 --------------------
 NULL

 Avg_pages   Max_pages   Min_pages   Ratio(Max/Avg)              Ratio(Min/Avg)
 ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------- ---------------------------
         863         863         863                    1.000000                    1.000000
Table LOB compression level
Lock scheme Datarows
The 'ascinserts' attribute is not applicable to tables with datarow or datapage lock schemes.

 exp_row_size reservepagegap fillfactor max_rows_per_page identity_gap ascinserts
 ------------ -------------- ---------- ----------------- ------------ -----------
            0              0          0                 0            0           0

(1 row affected)
 concurrency_opt_threshold optimistic_index_lock dealloc_first_txtpg
 ------------------------- --------------------- -------------------
                        15                     0                   0
(return status = 0)
```

Comment: have you tried to recreate a new table `select * into LOGING2` and then compare the contents of both tables?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using double-quotes, try using single-quotes:

```
DELETE 
FROM LOGIN 
WHERE login = '336959686@login.com';
```

If the delete statement produces no error but doesn't appear to delete the row affected, that means one of the following:

1. The criteria (the `WHERE` clause) is not matching the desired row.
2. You have a transaction that is rolling back the delete, or has not yet committed the delete.  Check the [transaction chaining mode](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X82816.htm) using `SELECT @@tranchained;`  Perhaps try this:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM LOGIN 
   WHERE login = '336959686@login.com';
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
   DELETE 
   FROM LOGIN 
   WHERE login = '336959686@login.com';
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
   SELECT *
   FROM LOGIN 
   WHERE login = '336959686@login.com';
   ```
3. Undetected database corruption - this is extremely rare.  Have you performed `DBCC CHECKDB` lately?  Make certain you have a reliable backup. Test the backup by restoring it onto another instance of Sybase ASE.  If you have done that, running DBCC CHECKDB should be performed. It may heavily impact I/O, so I would run it during non-peak hours.

Comment: 1. The clause is matching when `SELECT` , I can't see why it does not match for a `DELETE`    2. The row is still there  3. No I've never done it before , does I need to perform a check , is it safe ?

Comment: sp_help won't show if there is a trigger on the table. Run 'set triggers off' first to ensure no trigger can kick in. I don't think the issue is transactional however: if it was, then DELETE would show @@rowcount = 1 but the row would later appear not to be deleted; however, we see @@rowcount = 0 so it does not get deleted in the first place.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the query plan and I/O statistics from both the SELECT and the DELETE.